# alarms canceling ambiguity in AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i have two alarm:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(alarmType, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); //1
alarmManager.set(alarmType, cal.getTimeInMillis()-delaytime, pendingIntent); //2
```

and i want cancel alarm:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

The ambiguity is that which alarm was removed, 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PendingIntent's intent same then you had only one alarm. If alarmManager's pendingIntent's intent difference than you had two alarms.

Comment: PendingIntent's intent is same. But alarm fire time is different.

Comment: If intent same than alarm as same as the other one. For example I have a intent its name is test_intent. I create pengingIntent with this intent, pengingIntent's name is test1_pednging, second one is test2_pending. When I create alarm with these pending intances and use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT than I created only one alarm. Because of this test1_pendign set alarm after test2_pending setted other alam but overwrite before pending_intent(test1_pending). AlarmManager's flag equals FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.